# MySQL: Index for fast DISTINCT queries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

What index(es) to I need to set to get results as fast as possible for DISTINCT queries on a certain column?

Example table columns:

```
id        INTEGER
name      VARCHAR(32)
groupname VARCHAR(16)
```

Every so often I need to get a list of all groups,

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupname FROM data ORDER BY groupname
```

The table can have > 200k entries, but only about a dozen groups. I would like to not use a separate table for the group names, because the data get imported often from a CSV file.

Comment: hey. can't you make a separate table for groups and then add a relation to the mentioned table. so you can have a benefit of normalization and solve your problem!! even that the data is coning from CSV, you can use a good ETL like talend!

Comment: @mamdouh - That would be ideal, but he mentions he is trying to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: @EricPetroelje - ok. it was just a suggestion. anyway, I think adding an update-able View will solve his problem, isn't it!!

Comment: @mamdouh - Since he's using `DISTINCT` an updatable view wouldn't be possible here.  A materialized view would be a good option, but MySQL doesn't support those..

Comment: @EricPetroelje - What I meant with update-able view is that, as long as the group names changing is not frequent. whenever a new group is added then he can delete the previous one and add a new one. this way he will keep it updated. and for the first time he can make it manually. Just a thought. Loved to be discussed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, an index on `groupname` should get you the best possible results.

If that's not good enough, a couple more options to consider - first, you could cache the results of that query so that you only run it when you absolutely have to.  Second, you could create a separate table to store the `groupname` values and populate it via an insert trigger (this would avoid having to change your CSV import process)

Comment: what type of indices do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Indexing on groupname will solve your issue. If you are very much concern about the performance of your query while inserting/updating, then instead of indexing whole column try "**column prefix Indexing**".

Just adding indexes on varchar might slow down your insertion/updation as it need to update the index lookup for every write. For more information read BTree indexing algorithm